# WTForms doesn't validate - no errors

Tags: python, wtforms

I got a strange problem with the WTForms library. For tests I created a form with a single field:

```
class ArticleForm(Form):
    content = TextField('Content')
```

It receives a simple string as content and now I use `form.validate()` and it returns `False` for any reason.

I looked into the `validate()` methods of the `'Form` and `Field` object. I found out that the field returns true if the length of the errorlist is zero. This is true for my test as i don't get any errors. In the shell the validation of my field returns True as expected.

The `validate()` methode in the Form object just runs over the fields and calls their `validate()` method and only returns false if one of the fields is validated as false.

So as my Field is validated without any error i can't see any reason in the code why `form.validate()` returns `False`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

It seems to me, you just pass wrong values to your form. This is what you need to use such form:

```
from wtforms import Form, TextField # This is wtforms 0.6

class DummyPostData(dict):
    """
    The form wants the getlist method - no problem.
    """
    def getlist(self, key):
        v = self[key]
        if not isinstance(v, (list, tuple)):
            v = [v]
        return v

class ArticleForm(Form):
    content = TextField('Content')

form = ArticleForm(DummyPostData({'content' : 'my content' }))
print form.validate()
#$ python ./wtf.py 
#True
```

ps: It would be much better if you gave more explicit information: code examples and version of WTForms.

Comment: +1 for DummyPostData. I think it must be inside WTForms.

Comment: @paterdemin thaks! :)

Answer (score 0):

What are you passing to the form's constructor? You didn't provide any context on how the form is used.

The first argument to a form must be a form-data input wrapper. Valid ones include, but are not limited to:

- Django (`request.POST` or `request.GET`)
- Werkzeug (`request.form` or `request.args`)
- WebOb (depends; includes Pylon/Pyramid, TurboGears, and google appengine webapp framework)
- cgi.FieldStorage or equivalent

Use in a django-like view looks like:

```
def view(request, article_id):
    article = Article.objects.get(article_id)
    form = ArticleForm(request.POST, obj=article)
    if request.POST and form.validate():
        # do something
    # render stuff, etc
```