# How to manually create a form and then validate it in Flask wtform?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

How can I populate my form manually and then validate it?

```
class TestForm(Form):
    name = StringField('name', validators=[InputRequired()])
    age = IntegerField('age', validators=[InputRequired()])
```

I try to build the form with arbitrary data and validate:

```
data = {'name': 'bob', 'age': 33}
tform = TestForm(name=data['name'], age=data['age'])
if tform.validate():
    print 'success!'
else:
    print tform.errors
```

The result prints out errors:

```
{'age': [u'This field is required.']}
```

Which is odd because it didn't complain about `name`, even though I supplied both of them to the my `TestForm`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4773452/2800058) should help.

Answer (score 0):

try doing this instead

```
data = {'name': 'bob', 'age': 33}
tform = TestForm()
tform.name.data = data['name']
tform.age.data = data['age']
if tform.validate():
    print 'success!'
else:
    print tform.errors
```